Is every pure 1-qubit state an eigenstate of $aX + bY + cZ$?
As stated in the question, I have seen this claim made that a pure state can be written as an eigenstate of $aX + bY + cZ$ for some $a,b,c$ where $X,Y,Z$ are Pauli matrices. Why is this true and what are the restrictions on $a,b,c$? Is this also true for mixed states?

This is just a rephrasing of the Bloch sphere representation of a single qubit: any pure state $|\psi\rangle\in\mathbb C^2$, $\|\psi\|=1$ can be written as $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|=\frac12({\bf1}+aX+bY+cZ)$ for some $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb R^3$ with $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. But this implies the following chain of equivalent equalities
\begin{align*}
\big(|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|\big)|\psi\rangle&=\frac12({\bf1}+aX+bY+cZ)|\psi\rangle\\
|\psi\rangle\|\psi\|^2&=\frac12|\psi\rangle+\frac12(aX+bY+cZ)|\psi\rangle\\
\Big(1-\frac12\Big)|\psi\rangle&=\frac12(aX+bY+cZ)|\psi\rangle\\
|\psi\rangle&=(aX+bY+cZ)|\psi\rangle
\end{align*}
In other words $a,b,c$ are simply the components of the Bloch vector corresponding to $|\psi\rangle$.
For mixed state this question does not make sense—at least not without some adjustments—because a matrix $\rho$ can never be an eigenstate (vector!) of another matrix $aX+bY+cZ$.

TL;DR It is true that every pure one-qubit state is an eigenstate of some $aX + bY + cZ$. The restrictions are $a = xe^{i\phi}, b = ye^{i\phi}, c = ze^{i\phi}$ with $\phi\in[0, 2\pi)$ and $x,y,z\geq 0$. But the operator itself does not determine the eigenstate, since there will be two orthogonal eigenvectors. I would say that this is not true for mixed states simply because they are not represented as vectors, but matrices. Yet, there is some generalizing concept one could construct.
Also, the trivial case $a = b = c = 0$ obviously as every vector as eigenvector.
Details
Some preparations: Bloch sphere and rotations
I assume you are familiar with the Bloch sphere. Every pure one-qubit state can be written as
$$|\psi\rangle = \cos \frac{\theta}{2} |0\rangle + \sin \frac{\theta}{2} e^{i\phi} |1\rangle$$
neglecting global phases. Let's rewrite this as:
$|\psi\rangle = R_z(\phi) R_y(\theta) |0\rangle$
with $R_y(\alpha) = \exp\left(-i\frac{\alpha}{2}Y\right)$ and $R_z(\alpha) = \exp\left(-i\frac{\alpha}{2}Z\right)$.
I also define $\vec a := \begin{pmatrix}a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix}$ and $\vec \sigma = \begin{pmatrix} X \\ Y \\ Z \end{pmatrix}$ to rewrite your operator as $\vec a \vec \sigma = aX + bY + cZ$. Now, an important identity is:
$$R_y^\dagger(\theta) (\vec a \vec \sigma) R_y(\theta) = (O_y(-\theta)\vec a) \vec \sigma$$
where $O_y(-\theta)$ is a $y$-axis rotation with angle $-\theta$ in the 3-dim space that $\vec a$ lives in. For $R_z$, the same holds correspondingly.
Determining the eigenstates
With the above preparations we have
$$\vec a \vec \sigma |\psi\rangle = \vec a \vec \sigma R_z(\phi) R_y(\theta) |0\rangle = R_z (\phi) R_y(\theta) R_y^\dagger(\theta) R_z^\dagger(\phi) \vec a \vec \sigma R_z(\phi) R_y(\theta) |0\rangle = R_z(\phi) R_y(\theta) \vec a^\prime \vec \sigma |0\rangle $$
where I introduces identities in the form of self-annihilating rotations after the 2nd equal sign. Notice that $\vec a^\prime$ is a z- and y-rotated version of $\vec a$.
Using the above equation, how will $|\psi\rangle$ be an eigenvector of $\vec a \vec \sigma$? Answer: iff $\vec a^\prime = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ c \end{pmatrix}$ with $c \in \mathbb C$ (because this way, $\vec a^\prime \vec \sigma = cZ$ has $|0\rangle$ as an eigenvector).
To get $\vec a$ out of $\vec a^\prime$, you have to rotate back, first around the y-axis, then around the z-axis. Since the rotation angles $\theta$ and $\phi$ can be arbitrary this gives you vectors $\vec a = \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb C^3$ with the restriction that they must all share a common complex phase.
Operator does not fully determine eigenstate
Notice, that a given operator $aX + bY + cZ$ does not determine the eigenstate. Simple example: $Z |0\rangle = |0\rangle$ and $Z |1\rangle = - |1\rangle$. Yet, a given operator $aX + bY + cZ$ determines an orthonormal basis iff $|a|^2 + |b|^2 + |c|^2 > 0$.
Form of the eigenstate
A denstity matrix of a pure state can be written as
$$\rho = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \vec \beta \vec \sigma)$$
with $|\vec \beta|^2 = 1$. The eigenvectors will be the ones that where $\vec \beta$ and $\vec a$ only differ by a factor - or in other words: the vectors are linear dependent. (I skip the proof for that)
Mixed states
A mixed state is also represented by a density matrix of the form
$$\rho = \frac{1}{2}(1 + \vec \beta \vec \sigma)$$
with $|\vec \beta|^2 < 1$
If you want to define eigenstates for mixed states in the following way
$$ A \rho A^\dagger = a \rho$$
where $A$ is some operator and $a\in \mathbb C$, then you would get the same result as before that $\vec \beta$ and $\vec a$ have to be linear dependent.
